# Add TeamSpeak3 to Unity launcher?

Tags: 12.04, unity, installation, launcher, voip

How do I manually add something to the Unity Launcher? I downloaded the TeamSpeak 3 client, and though I can run it from the executable I'd really like to have a launcher icon on the unity launcher.

While TS3 is running there is an icon there and it even has the TS3 logo on the icon. It looks great when running. If I right-click that icon and "lock to launcher" the icon will stay but does not launch TeamSpeak when clicked.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have since discovered how to do this. I wrote a blog post to help others accomplish the same task.

http://www.codetunnel.com/blog/post/121/how-to-add-teamspeak-3-to-the-unity-launcher-in-ubuntu

I searched around for quite a while and just couldn't seem to find how to add custom applications to the Unity launcher (side bar) in Ubuntu. After much investigation I have found that applications that show up in the dashboard and on the Unity launcher have corresponding `appname.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications/`.

I created one for TeamSpeak 3 on my machine. Here is what my `Teamspeak3-client.desktop` file looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=3.0.6
Name=Teamspeak 3 Client
GenericName=Teamspeak
Exec=/home/alex/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=/home/alex/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/pluginsdk/docs/client_html/images/logo.png
StartupWMClass=Teamspeak
StartupNotify=true
```

Obviously you would modify the version number to reflect the version you have installed. Also double-check the path for the "Exec" and "Icon" options. My installation was located in my home directory.

Comment: My TeamSpeak directory does not contain a `logo.png` or even a `pluginsdk` directory.

Comment: Well this post is five years old now. It's probably all changed. I have no idea how much of this is valid anymore.

Comment: The code for the desktop entry worked! @kleinfreund : They changed the location of the `logo.png`. In the current version 3.2.3 you need to change the path to `TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/styles/default/logo-128x128.png`