# can't put .desktop into /usr/share/applications

Tags: 12.04

I have been following this post: [Add TeamSpeak3 to Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142764/add-teamspeak3-to-unity-launcher) I have created my .desktop file and it works create, now all the guides have been telling me to put this file in the /usr/share/applications folder but when i drag it there, I get this error:

There was an error moving the file into /usr/share/applications.

Error move file: Permission denied

I'm guessing the folder doesn’t have the correct permissions but none of the guides have mentioned this.

I'm wary changing permissions as I just had to reinstall my whole system after doing something similar which messed up my whole system when trying to install new apps.

Answer (score 5):

You need to be root to copy the file. I would recommend instead to copy to ~/.local/share/applications/, as this would not mess with the whole system.