# can't create desktop launchers in ubuntu 18.04, not even in root

Tags: 18.04, permissions, shortcuts

Please help me figure out how to create desktop shortcuts/launchers/whatever. When i try to copy and paste .desktop files from /usr/local/share or /usr/share, i get "permission is denied", even when I'm running file manager in root via pkexec. Same for when I try to create desktop launchers via "create launcher" in desktop operation. I tried editing the .desktop files I'm trying to get on my desktop (firefox and firestorm) to run its executions in root as well, permission still denied.

Any ideas? It doesn't even seem possible to me that while running in root I'm being denied permission to do anything.

edit note: I previously had referenced related articles I'd tried, but I can't seem to find the specific ones anymore, except: [can't put .desktop into /usr/share/applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147867/cant-put-desktop-into-usr-share-applications) . basically, the articles recommended the three things i've tried: running file manager in root; logging in as administrator; edit .desktop files to run in root.

Comment: _I know people have asked and found answers for this problem, except that none of their solutions are working for me_ Which articles, specifically, did you try and find wanting, so we can rules those out? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by changing permissions of Desktop from root to user with *chown*:

opening *home/[username]/*;
doing *sudo su*, entering user password;
using 
*chown [username] Desktop/*

voila